# How to export data from Cloud SQL to BigQuery on a daily basis?

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I have created a connection to Cloud SQL and used `EXTERNAL_QUERY()` to export the data to Bigquery. My problem is that I do not know a computationally efficient way to export a new days data since the Cloud SQL table is not partitioned; however, it does have a date column `date_field` but it is of the datatype `char`.

I have tried running the following query with the view of scheduling a similar type so that it inserts the results: 
 
 `SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("connection", "SELECT period FROM table where date_field = cast(current_date() as char);")`
 
  but it takes very long to run, whereas: 
 
 `SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("connection", "SELECT period FROM table where date_field = '2020-03-20';")`
 
  is almost instant.

Comment: In what environment do you want to run these queries?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I want to run those queries in BigQuery; the external queries are of the MySQL format.

Comment: Yes. But you want to automate this. Who will be running the queries, and in which environment. There are many ways to run queries in BigQuery...

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I will be using the scheduled query option in BigQuery to pull the latest day's data and append on the results. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it’s highly recommended to convert the ‘date_field’ column to the datatype DATE. This would improve simplicity and performance in the future.

When comparing two strings, MySQL will make use of indexes to speed up the queries. This is executed successfully when defining the string as ‘2020-03-20’ for example. When casting the current date to a string, it’s possible that the characters set used in the comparison aren’t the same, so indexes can’t be used.

You may want to check the characters set once current_datetime has been casted compared to the values in the ‘date_field’ column. You could then use this command instead of cast:
`CONVERT(current_date() USING enter_char_sets_here)`

Here is the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html) for the different casting functions.